# Conversion Tag on Event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a conversion pixel on a button tag, I want this pixel to fire when a user agrees to hit the submit button, and the URL does not change (just a thank you message pops up on the page). I already have a conversion tag on the page, but want to count those that hit this action button separately. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="javascript:null(void);" onClick="ftGoalTag19212();return false;">click here</a>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
function ftGoalTag19212(){
var ftRand = Math.random() + "";
var num = ftRand * 1000000000000000000;
var ftGoalTagPix19212 = new Image();
ftGoalTagPix19212.src = "http://servedby.flashtalking.com/spot/2531;19212;1515/?spotName=Demo_Thank_You&cachebuster="+num;
ftGoalTagPix19212.onload = ftLoaded19212;

}function ftLoaded19212() {
top.location.href="http://www.UrlGoesHere.pdf";
}
// -->
</script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `null(void);` is so invalid… Good you're returning false from the listener to prevent this from attempting execution.

Comment: We're in 2013. Change `<script language="javascript">
<!--` to `<script type="text/javascript">` immediately.

Comment: Sorry my background is very very lacking. What is the null(void) signifying? The user can't attempt the execution?

Comment: I will also change the script language to script tag. Thank you Bergi

Comment: Sorry for my phrasing. I meant that `null(void)` is a huge syntax error (try it in the console), but it is never getting executed because your `onclick` listener prevents the default action (following the href url). Which is good because attempts to interpret the snippet would have failed dramatically.